# How to communicate securely to an Database with electron?

Tags: database, mongodb, electron

I am creating an electron application that connects to an Database and do POST and GET requests to retrieve and insert data into it, the problem is that in the code i have defined my database uri ( im using mongodb)

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<myusesrname>:<mypassword>@cluster0.wqbiu.mongodb.net/query?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

like in the example above, but if i pack my electron app the connection to the database as well as the credentials its visible if someone unpacks the app.asar file and look in the server.js file how i can solve this problem? i dont want any security breaches neither for me or the people that will be using my application, thanks in advance for any answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application that requires a secure connection to something cannot afford to have any username's or password's hardcoded into its code.

Instead, a procedure of [authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) and [authorisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization) is utilised.

**Authentication** is used to verify the user. IE: They are who they say they are, often achieved via the use of some type of login form.

**Authorisation** is used to verify the logged-in user is allowed to access the requested resource. EG: Is this user allowed to retrieve a list of all users email addresses from the database.

As a rough guide, a user will login with their username and password. You could use OpenID as well here if you wanted. Once the user is 'logged-in' you could set a cookie or session and save the session id in the DB against the user. Of course, all of this is done over HTTPS.

There are various ways to control the validity of the session such as but not limited to refreshing the expiration date / time every time the user hits the server, auto timeout if the user has not interacted with the server for more than X minutes, etc.

In your app, the user could try and interact with the database at any time, but if the user is not logged in, the server could return the appropriate response and prompt the user to login. Some form of API here is really the way to go.

If the user is logged in then then next step is to authorise the users request, ensuring they are allowed to perform what they are asking before sending a response back. If they are not authorised to access the resource (EG: Edit another user’s post) then an appropriate response is returned indicating so.

As you can see, securing your app will take some work but the result of not doing so could be devastating to you and your users.